# DIV width and height wont resize when setting innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

When I set an image to the innerHTML of a DIV container, the width and height of the DIV is still not changed. The div has `border:solid` style and the border is like "outside" the image...

So the image is shown fully, but it streches outside the div borders, but still shows anyway. Is this a problem ?

Should I use the DOM method instead, will it be better ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you set the **overflow** css property of your div ?

http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp