# how to set the height of div tag using css

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DIV width and height wont resize when setting innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798926/div-width-and-height-wont-resize-when-setting-innerhtml)

I have a div tag and it has text written as inner HTML, like this for example:

```
<div>Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.........</div>
```

The inner HTML has a long text. Under the div tag I have kept an anchor tag. The problem is, when I shorten the height of div tag, say to 200px then the anchor tag comes over the inner HTML of div tag.

But, I want that when I shorten the height of div tag the inner HTML should also have the same height. I mean the anchor tag will appear just below the div tag and the div tag will have 200px height. I have googled around but didn't got much help. I hope I have made myself clear. If you have any doubts ask me please. I need help.

Comment: Try adding a http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can better understand your problem.

Comment: And could you show your actual HTML? Or at least something that accurately represents your actual HTML?

Comment: heres the jsfiddle.net link http://jsfiddle.net/TtG6C/

Comment: heres the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798926/div-width-and-height-wont-resize-when-setting-innerhtml :p
sorry folks

Comment: Hey Check to this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/TtG6C/8/ working fine...

Comment: If it's solved, accept the answer that gives the solution.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the height in % rather than px; so change your anchor tag height in % means height: 5% this will probably solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

set position property of your anchor tag to be relative

```
a#MyA
{
  top:100px;
  position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understant your problem correctly but at least in your jsfiddle link there was a lot of typos, corrected some and here's the [results](http://jsfiddle.net/fs69D/)

```
<div id="aa">Some Text. Some Text. Some Text. Some Text. Some Text. Some Text.Some Text.Some Text. Some Text. Some Text.Some Text.......</div>
    <div id="bb"><a href="#">Read More</a></div>​
```

Also added some colors for easier debugging.
Take a look at it.
Check [this too](http://jsfiddle.net/fs69D/3/), another possibility what you are trying to do...

```
div#aa {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #f00;
    overflow: hidden;
}

a {
    background-color: #aaf;
}
​
```

Comment: thanks but i have got the answer myself :) i have commented the answer on my question

Comment: @subhojit777 If any of answers would solve your problem you should accept it, stackoverflow is wiki after all and someone else may have same problem. Or maybe edit your first post to clearly point where others can found answer. Comments are not intended for that.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution for this problem:
[DIV width and height wont resize when setting innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798926/div-width-and-height-wont-resize-when-setting-innerhtml)

You have to add the overflow property for the div tag.